# Transforming a list containing key/value strings with jq

Tags: json, jq

So, I basically have a file `test.json`

```
[
  "Name=TestName",
  "Tag=TestTag"
]
```

Which I'd like to transform into

```
[
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Name",
    "ParameterValue": "TestName",
  },
  {
    "ParameterKey": "Tag",
    "ParameterValue": "TestTag",
  }
]
```

With `jq`. Any idea?

Comment: I tried a lot, trust me. `cat test.json | jq .[] | [.ParameterKey, .ParameterValue]` ....

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself preferably in a [Stack Snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See How to create a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It also very helpful to show in your Question an expected result, and quote any (exact) errors you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try [JQ Play](https://jqplay.org)

I tried with the following jq. It should work as long as you are sure of the format of the array.

`[.[] |  {ParameterKey: split("=")[0], ParameterValue: split("=")[1]}]`

If you are using from terminal, you can use the following option

`cat test.json | jq '[.[] |  {ParameterKey: split("=")[0], ParameterValue: split("=")[1]}]'`

Comment: You really don't need `cat`. Redirect input of `jq` directly with `<test.json jq '[.[] |  {ParameterKey: split("=")[0], ParameterValue: split("=")[1]}]'`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11710552/7939871

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to use `split()` call twice but just once and access the results directly with the Array/Object Value Iterator: `.[]` and specifying the index inside

```
jq -n '[ inputs[] | split("=") | {ParameterKey: .[0], ParameterValue: .[1]} ]'
```